# Pulling Data from Internet in android

Tags: android, xamarin

I am using Xamarin.android in visual studio & have successfully retrieved the data from online api and set it on a spinner using dynamic array, but when I dont have internet on my phone , the app stops . How to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check if you have internet access just when you open the app or just before making the request?

Comment: everything is available .  but maybe im doing something wrong . can u please provide any resource or code or example, that woulb be really very greatful